# python how to create an array based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I want to create an array with a format, and the values originate from another array. My input array consists out of three columns. I want to create an array with in the first row all values from the third column if the second column is equal. So in this example the first three values in the second column are equal, so in the new array i want the third value of each row in the new array.

```
a = 
[[1,  1,  4],
[2,  1,  6],
[3,  1,  7],
[4,  2,  0],
[5,  2,  7],
[6,  3,  1]]
```

result:

```
b = 
[[4, 6 , 7],
[0, 7],
[1]]
```

I tried:

```
c = []    
x = 1
for row in a:
    if row[0] == x
        c.extend[row[2]]
    else:
        x = x + 1
        c.append(row[2])
```

But the result is a list of all 3rd values

Comment: are the values in the second line increasing and integer?

Comment: Jep, they are all integer, and the values in the second column will only increase. However, the amount of values that are the same will vary

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.asarray(a)
c = []
for i in range(a[-1,1]): #a[-1,1] is the maximum that will occur
    save = a[a[:,1]==i] # take all the ones that have i in the second entry
    c.append(save[:,2]) # of those add the last entry
```

It's important, that `a`is converted to a `np.array` for this.

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me:

```
import numpy as np

c = [[]]    
x = 1
for row in a:
    if row[1] == x:
        c[-1].append(row[2])
    else:
        x = x + 1
        c.append([row[2]])

c = np.asarray(c)
```

Comment: The format is correct, but this results in a list consiting of lists, but because I need to do calculations with the result i prefer an array.

Comment: you can add `import numpy as np` and `c = np.asarray(c)`

Comment: This creates an object array. If i try to open it to preview i get the error object arrays are currently not supported (Spyder). 
My other arrays are the type float 64 and won't show this error..

Comment: I guess as @Psidom writes, the three arrays are unequal length. It's not possible to have one (float 64) array that contains the information presented in the three of them. So either you look at each array separately or go with the object array (array of three arrays), but that can't be displayed in Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

If the second column is sorted, you can use `np.diff` to find out the index where the value changes and then split on it:

```
np.split(a[:,2], np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a[:,1]) != 0)+1)
# [array([4, 6, 7]), array([0, 7]), array([1])]
```

Comment: This results in a list of arrays, is it also possible to create an array immediately?

Comment: You can wrap the result in `np.array(...)` to get an array, but Since the result arrays have different lengths, it will be an array of objects.  Normal useful numpy array operations won't apply here.

Comment: I would avoid wrapping it into an `np.array` as it will not behave as usual arrays. In case you really need it I would recommend creating a array with `np.nan` and then filling in your values, this will use to much information, but will be usable like a normal array.